# req.params not passing from React frontend to serverless function on Axios post request

Tags: reactjs, serverless, vercel

I have an edit form which is linked to a serverless function, in which a post request is made based on a Mongoose 'findById'.

The ID is successfully queried when the page is loaded, and the details of the database query are populated on the page.

However, when the post request is submitted, the req.query which was used to find the database entry, is then undefined.

Weirdly, the this.props.match.params.id returns the ID successfully on the client side, but it isn't going through to the serverless function.

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

Here's my code:

Serverless function -

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {


  await SubmitDebt.findById(req.query.id, function(err, submitdebt) {
    if (!submitdebt) {
      console.log(req.query.id);
      res.status(404).send("Unable to find entry to edit.");
    }
    else {
      console.log(req.query.id);
      submitdebt.creditCard = req.body.creditCard;
      submitdebt.personalLoan = req.body.personalLoan;
      submitdebt.provider = req.body.provider;
      submitdebt.balance = req.body.balance;
      submitdebt.limit = req.body.limit;
      submitdebt.monthly = req.body.monthly;
      submitdebt.interest = req.body.interest;
      submitdebt.borrowed = req.body.borrowed;

      submitdebt.save().then(submitdebt => {
        res.json("Debt successfully updated.");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("Debt unsuccessfully updated.");
      });
    }
  });

};
```

My edit component:

```
class EditDebt extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {

      balance: ''

    }

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }



  onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }

  onSubmit = async (e) => {

      e.preventDefault();

      console.log(this.props.match.params.id)

      await axios.post("/api/editDebtCard", { params: { id: this.props.match.params.id } }, {

        balance: this.state.balance

      })

      this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
    }

  render() {

    return (

      <section className="edit-debt-section">

      <div className="edit-debt-container">

      <form className="edit-debt-form" method="POST" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <div className="edit-debt-form-container">

          <label className="edit-debt-label">What's the balance?</label>
            <div className="edit-debt-input-container">
              <h6 className="edit-debt-input-text">£</h6>
              <input className="edit-debt-number-input" type="number" name="balance" value={this.state.balance} onChange={this.onChange} step="0.01" />
            </div>



          <button className="edit-debt-update-button" type="submit" name="button">Create</button>

          </div>
          </form>
      </div>

    </section>
    )

  }
}

export default EditDebt
```

I've removed the other functions and inputs from my component to make it more readable.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I have also tried it as 'req.params.id' instead of 'req.query.id', and unfortunately it says 'id is not defined'. Here's the code and the error message:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {


  await SubmitDebt.findById(req.params.id, function(err, submitdebt) {
    if (!submitdebt) {
      console.log(req.params.id);
      res.status(404).send("Unable to find entry to edit.");
    }
    else {
      console.log(req.params.id);
      submitdebt.balance = req.body.balance;

      submitdebt.save().then(submitdebt => {
        res.json("Debt successfully updated.");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("Debt unsuccessfully updated.");
      });
    }
  });

};
```

And the error message:

```
2020-10-24T12:05:51.806Z    279ac48e-af0b-49d1-bd13-4056f765ec40    ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined","reason":{"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"Cannot read property 'id' of undefined","stack":["TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined","    at module.exports (/var/task/api/editDebtCard.js:22:40)","    at Server.<anonymous> (/var/task/___now_helpers.js:813:19)","    at Server.emit (events.js:315:20)","    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:790:12)","    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined","    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)","    at process.emit (events.js:327:22)","    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"]}
Unknown application error occurred
```

Comment: You're probably right, but that's not the issue here I don't think.

Comment: Thanks! If you can provide an example of the code being restructured I’m happy to try and accept the answer if it works! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axios.post` method is `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`. So you should send `params` object in the third argument.

```
await axios.post("/api/editDebtCard",
  {
    balance: this.state.balance
  },
  {
    params: {
      id: this.props.match.params.id
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

On your react component you are giving the Id as a `req.params` and on your serverless function you are trying to read from `req.query` Can you try reading the id from the parameter?

```
await SubmitDebt.findById(req.params.id, function(err, submitdebt) {
    if (!submitdebt) {
      console.log(req.params.id);
      res.status(404).send("Unable to find entry to edit.");
    }
// ...
});
```

Comment: I believe ‘req.params.id’ returns ID as undefined unfortunately. I will try it again though and just confirm. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Hey, I've tried it and as expected it's saying 'id is not defined'. I've updated my original post with the code I tried and the error message.